# Using Oauth token created in JS in .Net client for getting google calendar events

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-oauth, google-calendar-api, google-api-js-client

I'm using the JS Quick Start [example](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/quickstart/js)
I have Inserted that example in a .Net Framework 4.7 Web App in the Index View.

I modified the listUpcomingEvents as follows

```
function listUpcomingEvents() {

      let data = {
          "email" : gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().currentUser.I4.value.Du.tv,
          "token" : gapi.client.getToken().access_token
      }

      fetch('http://localhost:53658/api/Default/', {
          method: 'GET',
          headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
              'userData': JSON.stringify(data)
          }
      })
          .then(response => {
          if (response.ok) { // if HTTP-status is 200-299
              // get the response body (the method explained below)
              response.text().then(myAnswer => {
                  console.log(myAnswer);
              })
          } else {
              console.error.log("HTTP-Error: " + response.status);
          }
      });

    gapi.client.calendar.events.list({
      'calendarId': 'primary',
      'timeMin': (new Date()).toISOString(),
      'showDeleted': false,
      'singleEvents': true,
      'maxResults': 10,
      'orderBy': 'startTime'
    }).then(function(response) {
      var events = response.result.items;
      appendPre('Upcoming events:');

      if (events.length > 0) {
        for (i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
          var event = events[i];
          var when = event.start.dateTime;
          if (!when) {
            when = event.start.date;
          }
          appendPre(event.summary + ' (' + when + ')')
        }
      } else {
        appendPre('No upcoming events found.');
      }
    });
  }
```

This is the code I have in the DefaultController/Get

```
const string ApplicationName = "Google Calendar API .NET Quickstart";
    const string clientId = "------";
    const string clientSecret = "-----";

    // GET: api/Default
    public string Get()
    {
        var re = Request;
        var headers = re.Headers;
        var jsonString = "";

        if (headers.Contains("userData"))
        {
            jsonString = headers.GetValues("userData").First();
        }
        gUserData? userData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<gUserData>(jsonString);

        // Create Google Calendar API service.
        var flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow(new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer
        {
            ClientSecrets = new ClientSecrets
            {
                ClientId = clientId,
                ClientSecret = clientSecret
            },
            Scopes = new[] { CalendarService.Scope.Calendar,
                             CalendarService.Scope.CalendarReadonly}
        });

        var credential = new UserCredential(flow, userData.email, new TokenResponse
        {
            AccessToken = userData.token
        });

        // Create Google Calendar API service.
        var service = new CalendarService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
        });

        // Define parameters of request.
        EventsResource.ListRequest request2 = service.Events.List("primary");
        request2.TimeMin = DateTime.Now;
        request2.ShowDeleted = false;
        request2.SingleEvents = true;
        request2.MaxResults = 10;
        request2.OrderBy = EventsResource.ListRequest.OrderByEnum.StartTime;

        // List events.
        Events events = request2.Execute();
        string sEvents = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(events.Items);

        return sEvents;
    }
```

All seems to be working... but when Events events = request2.Execute(); is executed I get the next error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'The access token has expired and could not be refreshed. Errors: refresh error, refresh error, refresh error'

Any Ideas?
The requirement is: the user must log in in the frontend, get the OAuth token, use it in the backend to save the data

Comment: Why are you not just doing this in .net why bring JavaScript into this?   Access tokens are only valid for an hour.  So if your token is expiring this is going to fail. You should just do this in .net.  However you should be aware there is a issue in the works to remove .net 4.* support from the google api .net client library soon.

Comment: Have you tried checking to see if the access token is even set at that point.

Comment: Yes, the Bearer Token is there. The client has a module in the back to process any rest service. 

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Glcpv4ZNSkR18FwIT5celdIwrrHeqMnj/view?usp=sharing

Comment: The rest services call will be processed in the backend, but we need the client's authorization to access their events. Is there a way to do that only in .net? maybe with user's email/password?

Comment: no by using Oauth2 and authorizing the user.   thats what GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow does.

Comment: ok. In this scenario what would be your recommendation?

Comment: Im a backend developer im probably not the best person to be asking.  but [web-applications-asp.net-core-3](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth#web-applications-asp.net-core-3)  I just think if you use Javascript in this manner your going to have issues when the access token expires your not going to be able to refresh it.  By just doing it in .net your going to have all that handled for you via the library.

Comment: Thank you, I'll see what I can do .net side.